# How to check either the series is convergent or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/4}}\log\left(\frac{n - 2}{n + 3}\right)$$Please, help me to solve it!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please try to make the title more descriptive, there are a lot of questions about checking whether the series is convergent or not.

Comment: I tried d'Alembert's ratio test, but it had not helped before I posted that question

Answer (score 9):

**HINT:**

> The sum needs to start at $n\ge 3$.

Note that we can write

$$\log\left(\frac{n-2}{n+3}\right)=\log\left(1-\frac{5}{n+3}\right)$$

and

$$-\frac{5}{n-2}\le \log\left(1-\frac{5}{n+3}\right)\le -\frac{5}{n+3}$$

Comment: Mark, thank You but that series do not start with n>=3, I checked it out. Could you go on Your reasoning?

Comment: If a series converges starting at some point, it converges (unless a term is undefined). However, for $n=1$ and $n=2$, how do you evaluate the terms?

Comment: Note that $\log(x)$, as a real-valued function, is undefined for $x\le 0$.  So, for $n=1$ and $n=2$ the term $\log(n-2)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** For $n\gt2$, we have $\log\left(\frac{n-2}{n+3}\right)\lt0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{n-2}{n+3}\right)
&=-\log\left(1+\frac5{n-2}\right)\\
&\ge-\frac5{n-2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I got it) Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Rob, note that the logarithm is multiplied by $n^{-1/4}$.

Comment: Yes, and that guarantees convergence. Note that the condition above implies $\left|\,\log\left(\frac{n-2}{n+3}\right)\,\right|\le\frac5{n-2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Using that
$$\ln (1+X) \sim X \;\;(X\to 0). $$

When $n\to+\infty $,

$$\ln (1-\frac {5}{n+3})\sim \frac {-5}{(n+3)} \sim \frac {-5}{n}$$

$$\implies u_n\sim \frac {-5}{n^{\frac {5}{4}}} $$

thus $\sum u_n $ is negative and converges.

Answer (score 0):

For a series to converge, all terms in it must be defined.

In this case, the first two terms are not defined, so the whole sum is undefined, and therefore does not converge.